# Checking for null does not suppress null dereference warning in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, null, visual-studio-2022, null-coalescing-operator

I have this simple method to get a value from a wrapped `DataTable`:

```cs
public string GetValue(int nodeID, string attributeName)
{
    DataRow row = this.dataTable.Rows[nodeID];
    var result = row.Field<string>(attributeName);
    return result.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

For some reason, Visual Studio insists there is a null dereference despite the null coalescing operator.
The n. c. operator should return an empty string exactly when a null is encountered, right?
What am I missing?

In the same class, there is this method overload with similar code, which doesn't raise the warning:

```cs
public string GetValue(string nodeName, string attributeName)
{
    var result = from row in this.dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 where row.Field<string>("nodeID") == nodeName
                 select row.Field<string>(attributeName);
    return result.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: What if `result` is null? The coalescing operator applies to the result of the needless `ToString()` call, not `result` itself. `Field<string>` already returns a string so there's no reason to use `ToString()`

Comment: `similar code` not at all. In fact this doesn't work. `result` in this case is an `IEnumerable<string>` which may be empty but not null. The result of `ToString()` won't be the field values, it will be the name of the type. You'd need `String.Join` to combine the values into a single string. Once again, the null coalescing operator isn't used.

Comment: Don't use `var result` but `string? result`, because that's what [`Field`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-8.0#system-data-datarowextensions-field-1(system-data-datarow-system-data-datacolumn)) returns. Then you notice that you should not use `ToString` without null-conditional-operator `.?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `row.Field<string>(attributeName)` returns a `string?` which is then used to invoke `ToString`, `result?.ToString() ?? string.Empty` should remove the warning.

In the second case, `result` is a non-null `IEumerable<string>` so no warning. Note that in this case `result.ToString()` will probably not produce the expected result.